# How to update UIPageControl when UIScrollView with PagingEnabled changes page?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

How do i make it so that when the user scrolls to a new page in UIScrollView, the UIPageControl updates?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I have used this before and it seemed to work well. Be sure to set the UIScrollView.delegate to self.

```
#pragma mark - UIScrollViewDelegate methods

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)sender {
    uint page = sender.contentOffset.x / width;
    [self.pageControl setCurrentPage:page];
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Where you defined your UIScrollView and UIPageControl, you have to implement this method :

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)_scrollView
{
    if (pageControlIsChangingPage)
        return;

    CGFloat pageWidth = _scrollView.frame.size.width;
    int page = floor((_scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
    pageControl.currentPage = page;
}
```

and this one :

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)_scrollView 
{
    pageControlIsChangingPage = NO;
}
```

where `pageControlIsChangingPage` is :

```
BOOL    pageControlIsChangingPage;
```

Comment: That's what I did at first, but picciano's answer is more correct: if you handle `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating`, you don't get “false alerts” while animating.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an update of this answer for Swift as well:

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
            pageControl.currentPage = Int(myScrollView.contentOffset.x) / Int(myScrollView.frame.width)
        }
```