# UIPageControl Current page indicator switches before new view is presented

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

I have implemented a nice`UIPageViewControl` with a`PageControl`. When swiping the indicator changes and shows the correct current page.

However i noticed that all that it takes for the current page indicator to switch is to start swiping. Meaning if i start swiping but then let go of the finger the current page indicator has switched like the page has been switched however it has not. This is the code that i am using to make the switch:

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated{

    NSUInteger index = [self.navigationController.viewControllers indexOfObject:viewController];
    self.pageControl.currentPage = index;
}
```

Another thing i noticed was that when i swipe right and left changing views FAST the page indicator is just stuck and does not move.

So it only works when you are not changing views fast. If you need any additional code let me know. Thank you.

**Edit**

This is the code i use to implement my UIPageViewController.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Create the data model

    self.navigationItem.title = @"Tabell";
    self.identifiers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [self.identifiers addObject:@"rankTable"];
    [self.identifiers addObject:@"page2"];

    // Create page view controller
    self.pageViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageViewController"];
    self.pageViewController.dataSource = self;
    self.pageViewController.delegate = self;


    self.navigationController.delegate = self;
    CGSize navBarSize = self.navigationController.navigationBar.bounds.size;
    CGPoint origin = CGPointMake( navBarSize.width/2, navBarSize.height/2 );
    self.pageControl = [[UIPageControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(origin.x, origin.y+16,
                                                                       0, 0)]; //Here added 45 to Y and it did the trick


    self.pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = navbarColor;
    self.pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

    [self.pageControl setNumberOfPages:2];

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:self.pageControl];

    UITableViewController *startingViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *viewControllers = @[startingViewController];
    [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];

     CGFloat tabBarHeight = self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.height;

    // Change the size of page view controller
    self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - tabBarHeight);

    [self addChildViewController:_pageViewController];
    [self.view addSubview:_pageViewController.view];
    [self.pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

}
```

Comment: While changing views fast, it doesn't move at all or it moves after finishing moving?

Comment: it does not move at all. @sasquatch

Comment: Not a duplicate, but similar technique you can use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6310031/how-to-update-uipagecontrol-when-uiscrollview-with-pagingenabled-changes-page/6310093#6310093

Comment: I dont get how that is implemented. What has the width for value? @picciano

Comment: It's the page width, often the same as the scroll view width.

Comment: Check the edit i made. I dont believe i can use your method since  i use that way to implement UIPageViewController? If i am wrong please do provide with a code sample of how i can solve it. @picciano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you implement the `UIPageViewControllerDelegate`'s

`- pageViewController: didFinishAnimating: previousViewControllers: transitionCompleted:` method? It has a `transitionCompleted` boolean which tells you if you should update your page control. Your current implementation seems to be buggy because as soon as you star swiping a page, it loads a view controller for the next page and calls the `...didShow...` method. Hope this hepls.

Comment: I tried to implement this. I put a NSLog inside the function, it worked just as my current function. The NSLog fired as soon as i started swiping?

Comment: Did you check the 'transitionCompleted' boolean?